# SetEnv in xampp/apache .htaccess returns error 503

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

My .htaccess file

```
    SetEnv PERCORSO_GLOBALS "D:\WEB\htdocs\globals.php"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

    ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400badrequest.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401authreqd.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403forbid.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404notfound.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500serverr.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /errors/503servunav.html

    Options All -Indexes
```

At home this files works with xampp end PERCORSO_GLOBALS is correctly set and can be use in php with `$_SERVER['PERCORSO_GLOBALS']`.

On my office computer, same configuration (Win7+xampp), i get always the `503` error.

**N.B. the error I get is not the standard 503 error, but my personal 503 error setted on the .htaccess file (`ErrorDocument 503 /errors/503servunav.html`)**

If I remove from the file this line:

```
    SetEnv PERCORSO_GLOBALS "D:\WEB\htdocs\globals.php"
```

then the server works...
But I need this enviroment variable everywhere, cause I include this file on each other file.

What should I change to make it works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SetEnvIf` instead:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" PERCORSO_GLOBALS=D:\WEB\htdocs\globals.php
```

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and see what error are you getting.

Comment: If there is 503 then it has to be some error as 503 means `Service Unavailable`

Comment: Last line are from 15 minutes befor my last page refresh which generates a 503

Comment: Obviously this `SetEnvIf` cannot generate 503 so you will need to look into your setup to see why that is showing up

Comment: If I remove this line from the file then no error is generated

Comment: For testing try this line: `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" a=1`

Comment: Try: `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" PERCORSO_GLOBALS=D:/WEB/htdocs/globals.php`